# Next.js, Strapi - Fetch response is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, next.js, strapi

I have nextjs frontend that fetch data from strapi backend.
Problem is that data is empty even if i can see on strapi dev logs that request has been made.

This is next.js code

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Room = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  let fetchData;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.asPath !== router.route) {
      getDataNames();
    }
  }, [router]);

  const getDataNames = () => {
    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:1337/rooms?_id=" + router.query.id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => (fetchData = data));
      console.log(fetchData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{router.query.id}</p>
      <p>{fetchData}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Room;
```

And here is the strapi log

```
[2021-02-23T14:06:20.845Z] debug GET /rooms?_id=6034aac1ba63472e9878ed25 (27 ms) 200
```

But I don't know why is data empty.
Truth is that the response consist of base64 long text but I am not sure if that can cause the problem.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: use state not a variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const Room = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  //let fetchData;
  const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.asPath !== router.route) {
      getDataNames();
    }
  }, [router]);

  const getDataNames = () => {
    try {
      fetch("http://localhost:1337/rooms?_id=" + router.query.id)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => { setFetchData(data); });
      console.log(fetchData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{router.query.id}</p>
      <p>{fetchData}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can use `useState` hook for React state.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` and set state are both asynchronous, so your code will get to `console.log(fetchData);` while the fetch and the set state are both still being run.

If you add another useEffect for when `fetchData` is changed you'll see the updated value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(fetchData);
}, [fetchData]);
```